# unit test fails in edit _get action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, nunit, moq

i wrote a unit test for edit_get action
My controller action is

```
 public class GroupController : Controller
  {
     private readonly IGroupService groupService;
     public GroupController(IGroupService groupService)
     {
       this.groupService = groupService;
      }
      public ActionResult EditGroup(int id)
       {
          var group = groupService.GetGroup(id);
          CreateGroupFormModel editGroup = Mapper.Map<Group, CreateGroupFormModel>(group);
          if (group == null)
           {
            return HttpNotFound();
          }
           return View("_EditGroup", editGroup);
       }
```

the controller actionis working fine.
but when i am writing my unit test it get failed
my test is

```
[Test]
    public void Edit_Get_ReturnsView()
    {
    //Arrange
    CreateGroupFormModel group = new CreateGroupFormModel()
    {
     GroupId = 2, 
     GroupName = "Test",

     Description = "test" };
     GroupController controller = new GroupController();
    var fake = groupService.GetGroup(2);
    groupRepository.Setup(x => x.GetById(2)).Returns(fake);
    Mapper.CreateMap<CreateGroupFormModel, Group>().ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Ignore());
    Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    ViewResult actual = controller.EditGroup(2) as ViewResult;
    Assert.IsNotNull(actual, "View Result is null");
   }
```

can any one help me. the test fails as

```
Expected Not Null
actual Null
```

Comment: How you stub out the groupService?

Comment: Also you might want to check your mapping configuration is correct in Mapper.Map<Group, CreateGroupFormModel>(group); If the groupService returns a group that cannot be mapped you might get null "editGroup" so the test fail.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller action you are calling `var group = groupService.GetGroup(id);` and it is not very clear where this `groupService` is coming from. In your unit test you must mock it.  For this to be possible your `GroupController` must take this dependency as constructor injection.

Also in your unit test you seem to have declared some `group` variable which is never used.

For example:

```
public class GroupController: Controller
{
    private readonly IGroupService groupService;
    public GroupController(IGroupService groupService)
    {
        this.groupService = groupService;
    }

    public ActionResult EditGroup(int id)
    {
        var group = this.groupService.GetGroup(id);
        CreateGroupFormModel editGroup = Mapper.Map<Group, CreateGroupFormModel>(group);
        if (group == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View("_EditGroup", editGroup);
    }
}
```

and now in your unit test you could mock this group service and provide expectations on the result of the GetGroup method:

```
[Test]
public void Edit_Get_ReturnsView()
{
    // arrange
    var group = new CreateGroupFormModel 
    {
        GroupId = 2,
        GroupName ="Test", 
        Description ="test" 
    };
    var groupServiceMock = new Mock<IGroupService>();
    groupServiceMock.Setup(x => x.GetGroup(group.GroupId)).Returns(group);
    var sut = new GroupController(groupServiceMock.Object);
    Mapper.CreateMap<CreateGroupFormModel, Group>().ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Ignore());
    Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

    // act
    var actual = sut.EditGroup(group.GroupId) as ViewResult;

    // assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(actual);
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(typeof(ViewResult), actual);
}
```

Comment: group service is coming from a repository and this repository is  mocked

Comment: @RintuMary, in the sample unit test code you have shown this doesn't seem to be the case. I can't see where you have mocked this service. Take a look at my answer for an example of how this could be achieved.